# Formatting a date as a string, from bean to javascript

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc, struts-1

In my bean, I'm formatting a date as a string:

```
 public void setStrDate(Date dte) {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    this.strDate = df.format(dte);
 }
```

In my js file, I'm grabbing the data:

```
 $('#content').data("myDate", <c:out value="${myBean.strDate}"/>);
```

And in my js, displaying the data:

```
 $('#sideBar').find("p[class=stat]").append($('#content').data("myDate"));
```

The date comes over as 10/10/2014. I even see it in the developer tools this way:
     $('#content').data("myDate", 10/10/2014);

But on the webpage, it shows up as 0.0004965243296921549

How can I format this?

Comment: why is this tagged as struts-1 , spring-mvc ?

Comment: Because that's the type / related technologies being used in the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put quotes around your date when you output it. Make it read:

```
 $('#content').data("myDate", "<c:out value="${myBean.strDate}"/>");
```

*Why is it resulting in 0.0004965243296921549*

10/10/2014 is actually being evaluated as math, `10/10 = 1` `->` `1/2014=0.0004965243296921549`

---

*if this code `"<c:out value="${myBean.strDate}"/>"` is making your editor flip out about the quotes then you can use single quotes as well `'<c:out value="${myBean.strDate}"/>'`